# Symfony2.7 FOSUser save user and user info into different tables

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.7

Ok, so I am trying to save User to users table in my database and User info like name, surname to user_info table, using FosUserBundle what I have now is OneToOne bidirectional relation between these tables, form which save User and User info correctly but user_id in user_info table is always null I am trying to do this since 4 hours and now I have no idea what to do.

**Edit:
I've managed it myself, didn't need bidirectional relation, will mark changes in files**

Entity Users

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Users
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\UsersRepository")
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Users extends BaseUser
{
 /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;


   //don't need mappedBy option and that is whole relation statement
    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserInfo", //mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist","remove"})

    */
    private $profil;


   public function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
   }

    /**
     * Set profil
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\UserInfo $profil
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setProfil(\AppBundle\Entity\UserInfo $profil = null)
    {
        $this->profil = $profil;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get profil
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\UserInfo
     */
    public function getProfil()
    {
        return $this->profil;
    }
}
```

UserInfo entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * UserInfo
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UserInfo
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_name", type="string", length=255)
     */

    private $userName;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_surname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $userSurname;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="blood_donated")
     */
    private $bloodDonated;

    /**
     * Get id    
     *
     * @return integer
     */

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set userName
     *
     * @param string $userName
     *
     * @return UserInfo
     */
    public function setUserName($userName)
    {
        $this->userName = $userName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserName()
    {
        return $this->userName;
    }

    /**
     * Set userSurname
     *
     * @param string $userSurname
     *
     * @return UserInfo
     */
    public function setUserSurname($userSurname)
    {
        $this->userSurname = $userSurname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userSurname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserSurname()
    {
        return $this->userSurname;
    }

    /**
     * Set bloodDonated
     *
     * @param string $bloodDonated
     *
     * @return UserInfo
     */
    public function setBloodDonated($bloodDonated)
    {
        $this->bloodDonated = $bloodDonated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bloodDonated
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBloodDonated()
    {
        return $this->bloodDonated;
    }     
}
```

And forms:

RegistrationFormType:

```
namespace UsersBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface; 
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;
use AppBundle\Form\UserInfoType as UserInfoType;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){

        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        //adding profil hidden field to set profil in table, here whole magic happens at $builder -> add('profil','hidden')

        $builder ->add('profil','hidden')
        ->add('profil', new UserInfoType(), array('data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\UserInfo'))
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_user_registration';
    }
}
```

and UserInfoType:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserInfoType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('userName')
            ->add('userSurname')
            ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\UserInfo'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_userinfo';
    }
}
```

**Edit So I needed 2 changes actually add profil input to form and fix my relation between tables, hope it will help someone**

Comment: Did you get it fixed ? I stll have the same prob with 3 tables.

Comment: @megadruck Yes, this was long ago, but if I remember correctly I've added hidden profil input in builder 
$builder ->add('profil','hidden')
        ->add('profil', new UserInfoType(), array('data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\UserInfo')) ;

And removed mappedBy option in relation statement in Users class